# Why don't std::atomic<integral> specializations provide multiplication and division assignment operators?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic

The full specializations of std::atomic for integral types provide arithmetic compound assignment operators such as `+=`, `-=`, but no `*=` or `/=`. The standard states this but as far as I can see there is no reason given. Could someone familiar with the reasoning behind the Atomic Operations Library section shed some light on this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think this is related to hardware. Many platforms have atomics to handle `+=` but I don't know of any that offers `*=`. Implementing this through locking would be simple, but the interface of `std::atomic` would be mixing at the same level operations that are somehow cheap with very expensive operations.

Comment: That was my suspicion. I guess that's why there are bitwise AND, OR and XOR ops but no bit shifting ones.